# What's the effect called when only certain subjects are in colour while the rest is black & white?

Tags: terminology, color, effect, black-and-white, selective-color

what is the technical term for such pictures?

Those with the special characteristics black&white, with a single color?

[image]

Comment: In print media, it would be termed 'spot color'. Digitally, 'shopped' might be usefully applied.

Comment: Welcome to this site Dirk. Do you see that other question suggested as duplicate by @mattdm? Please compare just the two titles. Do you see how the other title is very informative and summarises the concrete issue? Your question title is **very** generic and would apply to many questions about pictures with special characteristics. When asking a question, please try to be more specific.

Comment: @null Although note that the other question started as "What is this color filter effect?" until I retitled it. I'm glad I did, though, because that's how I was able to find it so quickly again when I went to look for it here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selective Colorization is the name of this editing technique.

Comment: "Selective colorisation" might only be accurate if the photo was originally black and white and a selected colour is laid on some object, but from what I see, it's more often done with colour photos of which only a certain colour is kept. "Selective colour" might be the better term.

Comment: Maybe more accurate to say "Selective de-colourisation", as the colour is being removed from parts. Or "selective desaturation" is a more common term for photos.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find it as "selective black and white".